# AngularJS factory in controller get error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I using the following code to use factory and I get this error-

> Error: [$injector:undef] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/undef?p0=ShowService

this is the code for the controller-

```
'use strict';

app.controller("LoginController", function (ShowService) {

var model = this;

//function call when user submit the login form
model.login = function (useremail, password) {
    var data = {useremail:useremail, password,password};
    var url = "/php/user-login.php";
    ShowService.UserLogin(url,data);
}
});
```

and here is the code for the factory-

```
'use strict';

app.factory('ShowService', dataService);

function dataService($http) {
var data = {
    "UserLogin": UserLogin,
}

function UserLogin(postUrl, data) {
    return $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        data: data
    })
}
}
```

Comment: have you refered the js files?

Comment: Hi, did you minify your files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `return` statement of your `factory`. There is also a typo on your `data` var with the extra comma.

You should do it like this:

```
function dataService($http) { 
  var data = { 
    UserLogin: UserLogin
  }
  return data;

  function UserLogin() {
   //whatever
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot to return your `data` variable when creating `ShowService`.

And take care to inject the necessary dependencies for both your controller and service. Stark's answer might be helpful with that.

```
'use strict';

function dataService($http) { 
    function UserLogin(postUrl, data) {
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: post_url,
            data: data
        });
   }

    var data = { "UserLogin": UserLogin};
    return data;
}

dataService.$inject = ["$http"];

app.factory('ShowService', dataService);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line 
             **var data = {useremail:useremail, password,password};**   as **var data = {useremail:useremail, password: password};**

Answer (score -2):

Use `$scope` in controller instead of `this`.

```
app.controller("LoginController", ['$scope', 'ShowService', function ($scope, ShowService) {


//function call when user submit the login form
$scope.login = function (useremail, password) {
  var data = {useremail:useremail, password,password};
  var url = "/php/user-login.php";
  ShowService.UserLogin(url,data);
}
}]);
```